# One of the same two pages has"unexpected token <" error, while the other works perfectly right

Tags: javascript

I have the same two pages. First I've created one, included all css-js files which are neccessary, and then I have copied all the codes inside this page. Next, I created second page.

By the way, these two pages are in the same folder. Thus, if the first page can include all the js-css files, second page can do the same without any errors.

When I open the page that I created firstly, it works perfectly. Zero errors. 
However, when I click on a button on the page to be redirected to the second page that I created, page looks broken.

This error writes in the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

I'm stucked in this stupid error for two days, I get nothing.

All I did is: Ctrl+A, ctrl+c, ctrl+v.

Any help would be perfect.

EDIT: I solved it by changing backend function from "render" to "redirect". I still have the same error but the page looks fine and this was all I need.

Comment: You have a broken link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230614/5734311 Look at the source of the second page (press Ctrl+U), then check all the `src` and `href` attributes by clicking them.

Comment: Checked them all. No problem with those links. Both pages have the same links. With any broken link, first page would have been broken too.

Comment: Can you put the project on github or the like so we can take a look? Or is it hosted online already?

Comment: Maybe the most common reason for "unexpected token <" error is some HTML markup included in .js or .json file, ex. a script tag in a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Check you links url. Is it correct? 
Try to open you second page without link clicking. Is it working?

Comment: Yes, I checked the url. No problem with that. And tried to open second page without clicking as you said, it work fine again. I dont understand why is this happening.

I think I'm going to punch the computer XD Maybe it helps to solve...

Comment: Show me you link to second page. Problem is in bocken link. Is url the same when you open page from link and without it